# training data augmentation in caffe along with its multilabel

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, face-detection, keypoint

## How to randomly crop training images along with its position label.

I'm preprocessing images data and its labels for caffe input. I want to crop my training images randomly online (when caffe running) and I know caffe provide a random crop param in layer [random crop](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/training-and-deploying-deep-learning-networks-with-caffe-optimized-for-intel-architecture). The issues is that my label of each corresponding image is variant when image is transformed. So in this way I have to change my label together with transformed image. I try to search my issue long time, but no use. Then I realized maybe there were two ways to solve the issues:

1. get the offset of random crop image on original image. But I googled it with no answer about it.
2. I'll specify the random offset online, then crop image by the specific offset [crop specific offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588943/caffe-fully-convolutional-cnn-how-to-use-the-crop-parameters). But how can i generate a random number when caffe training time.
3. I kown preprocessing the random crop image and its label offline may be a workable method. However, it will occupied considerable space of disk, for my data-set for training is too large.

**my position corresponding label:**
I split each of training image as `10x10=100` grids. the label is the index of grid for specific keypoint in image. for instance, the label will be 11, when my head key-point is at position of `<2th row, 1th col>` grid of image.

Comment: and I also kown that the issue could be solved by Caffe Python Layer. But it seems that the training time will be long when I use Python Layer in prototxt [as this mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633624/caffe-image-augmentation-by-cropping). If it is necessary to use this API, then how to use it in this concrete issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`"Python"` layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41344168/1714410) for this task, as you already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444526/training-data-augmentation-in-caffe-along-with-its-multilabel#comment70095764_41444526) (and I suppose this is the easiest way around).
If you are concerned with running time of this layer, you can make it multi-thread: have the layer invoke several threads to crop images and re-compute their labels. These threads will run at the background and should be able to provide the net with enough data in time for the next mini batch.

See python [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module for the `Thread` class. You might also find it convenient to use [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class to sync the threads and the main input layer.

Comment: ok, I'll try that tonight. by the way, How can I check  whether my own Python layer works or not. In another word, can I print out my data structure after my Python layer?

Comment: @farever you should write a test for your layer.